# strange behaviour of java getBytes vs getBytes(charset)

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-32

consider the following:

```
public static void main(String... strings) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = { -30, -128, -94 };

    //section utf-32
    String string1 = new String(b,"UTF-32");
    System.out.println(string1);   //prints ?
    printBytes(string1.getBytes("UTF-32")); //prints 0 0 -1 -3 
    printBytes(string1.getBytes());  //prints 63

    //section utf-8
    String string2 = new String(b,"UTF-8"); 
    System.out.println(string2);  // prints •
    printBytes(string2.getBytes("UTF-8"));  //prints -30 -128 -94 
    printBytes(string2.getBytes());  //prints -107 
}

public static void printBytes(byte[] bytes){
    for(byte b : bytes){
        System.out.print(b +  " " );
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

output:

```
?
0 0 -1 -3 
63 
•
-30 -128 -94 
-107
```

so I have two questions:

1. in both sections : why the output `getBytes()` and `getBytes(charSet)` are different even though I have specifically mentioned the string's charset
2. why both of the byte outputs of `getByte` in section utf-32 are different from the actual `byte[] b`? (i.e. how can I convert back a string to its original byte array?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

> in both sections : why the output `getBytes()` and `getBytes(charSet)` are different even though I have specifically mentioned the string's charset

The character set you've specified is used during *character encoding* of the string to the byte array (i.e. in the method itself only). It's not part of the `String` instance itself. You are *not* setting the character set for the string, the character set is not stored.

Java does not have an internal byte encoding of the character set; it uses arrays of `char` internally. If you call `String.getBytes()` without specifying a character set, it will use the *platform default* - e.g. Windows-1252 on Windows machines.

---

Question 2:

> why both of the byte outputs of `getByte` in section utf-32 are different from the actual `byte[] b`? (i.e. how can I convert back a string to its original byte array?)

You cannot always do this. Not all bytes represent a valid encoding of characters. So if such an encoded array is decoded then these kind of encodings are *silently ignored*, i.e. the bytes are simply skipped.

This already happens during `String string1 = new String(b,"UTF-32");` and `String string2 = new String(b,"UTF-8");`.

You can change this behavior using an instance of [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html), retrieved using [`Charset.newDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newDecoder--).

---

If you want to *encode* a random byte array into a String instance then you should use a hexadecimal or [base 64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) *encoder*. You should not use a *character decoder* for that.

Answer (score 2):

Java **String / char** (16 bits UTF-16!) **/ Reader / Writer** are for Unicode text. So all scripts may be combined in a text.

Java **byte** (8 bits) **/ InputStream / OutputStream** are for binary data. If that data represents text, one needs to know its encoding to make text out of it.

So a conversion from bytes to text always needs a Charset. Often there exists an overloaded method without the charset, and then it defaults to the `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` which can differ on every platform.
Using a default is absolutely non-portable, if the data is cross-platform.

*So you had the misconception that the encoding belonged to the String. This is understandable, seeing that in C/C++ unsigned char and byte were largely interchangeable, and encodings a nightmare.*

Comment: UTF-16 encodes Unicode, and needs in the mentioned case use a "surrogate" pair of chars to encode one. The encoding is safe as UTF-8, marking high bits. Hence `int String.codePointAt(int i)` and `Character.charCount(int cp)`. You are right to see text in java as amorph "Unicode". On the moment you need bytes, UTF32 might be an option. Casting UTF-8 byte or UTF-16 char will only be partially correct, and is a no-no.

Comment: I thought so to, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613779/is-a-java-char-array-always-a-valid-utf-16-big-endian-encoding) it is mused that that may not be the case and I was wrong. `char` arrays seem to be always UTF-16BE as *long as the underlying string is*. Note the person asking the question :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes, it was a visionary laudable design decision at that time, to let `String` be Unicode text, `char` 2 bytes, and binary data use `byte[]`. Upto today one sometimes other languages have their small troubles.