# Is a Java char array always a valid UTF-16 (Big Endian) encoding?

Tags: java, arrays, unicode, character-encoding, char

Say that I would encode a Java character array (`char[]`) instance as bytes:

- using two bytes for each character
- using big endian encoding (storing the most significant 8 bits in the leftmost and the least significant 8 bits in the rightmost byte)

Would this always create a valid UTF-16BE encoding? If not, which code points will result in an invalid encoding?

---

This question is very much related to [this question about the Java char type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112435/how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type) and [this question about the internal representation of Java strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You can create `char` instances that contain any 16-bit value you desire---there is nothing that constrains them to be valid UTF-16 code units, nor constrains an array of them to be a valid UTF-16 sequence. Even `String` does not require that its data be valid UTF-16:

```
char data[] = {'\uD800', 'b', 'c'};  // Unpaired lead surrogate
String str = new String(data);
```

The requirements for valid UTF-16 data are set out in [Chapter 3](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch03.pdf) of the Unicode Standard (basically, everything must be a Unicode scalar value, and all surrogates must be correctly paired). You can test if a `char` array is a valid UTF-16 sequence, and turn it into a sequence of UTF-16BE (or LE) bytes, by using a `CharsetEncoder`:

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-16BE").newEncoder();
ByteBuffer bytes = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(data)); // throws MalformedInputException
```

(And similarly using a `CharsetDecoder` if you have bytes.)

Comment: *If* the `String` contains only valid Unicode, then `toCharArray()` is necessarily valid UTF-16BE---but, as I mentioned, `String` doesn't validate its contents, so it's up to you to check this.